# Is the history of EC2 instance scheduled events available anywhere?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to get a history on scheduled events on an [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance from `ec2.describe_instance_status.instance_statuses` or an alternate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think AWS stores historical information for this. But they should be sending an email to the email associated with the AWS account every time an instance is scheduled for maintenance, so that may be the best place to find historical events.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html

Answer (score 2):

You can see the history of scheduled events via the [AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/personal-health-dashboard/).

You should be able to access these programmatically too: *[health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/health/index.html)*

Answer (score 0):

chck **/JobFlowId/node/**

Node logs, including bootstrap action, instance state, and application logs for the node. The logs for each node are stored in a folder labeled with the identifier of the EC2 instance of that node.

for every commit, there will be a log file that stores all the data. you can retrieve.
else contact support.